# How many mini-cassettes does Soundwave have?

Tags: transformers

According to,

[List of the Transformers, cassettes warriors](https://neoencyclopedia.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_The_Transformers_characters:_Cassette_warriors)

In the 80's Transformers cartoon, Soundwave has 8 mini-cassetes: 2 condors, a panther, 2 robots, a bat, a stegosaurus and a Tyrannosaurus rex.

However, at least in episode 27 of season 2, he releases a 3 wheels explorer robot, which is inmediately destroyed. Is this the only not listed Soundwave mini-cassette in G1 Transformers ?

How many mini-cassettes does Soundwave have?

Comment: I bet he's got an _amazing_ Grateful Dead bootleg in there somewhere.

Comment: I had *dozens* of transformers bootleg audiotapes.

Comment: Play ‘Free Bird’.

Comment: A much better fan wiki is https://tfwiki.net whose page about the [Decepticon Mini-Cassettes](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Decepticon_Mini-Cassette) names **eighteen** as mentioned in the "Generation 1 continuity", plus clones and unnamed recolours, although the same eight are described as having named appearances in the original cartoon.

Comment: oh, there it is the mini cassette I was talking about, it's called Autoscout